# Path of the UDP packet from kernel to user-space in Linux

Tags: c, linux, udp, linux-device-driver

I'm maintaining some network driver and I've got some problems with lost of data. The effect is that when I send for example ICMP or UDP ping using ping or nping some of the udp/icmp packets are lost.

I'm sure that on ping/nping side of the transmission the ping reply is received by my driver and the kernel (tcpdump shows incoming udp or icmp packets as a reply).

But application ping/nping shows sometimes that for example 80% packets are lost. I suspect that those packets are lost somewhere between kernel and user space.

I know that for UDP there is procedure udp_rcv() for maintenance of UDP packets, but I don't know which procedure is next in the path of delivering of the packet to user space application.

Linux kernel is in version 3.3.8.

My question is - how to trace the whole path of transition of the packet from my driver to user space socket buffer?

Comment: Maybe with [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/)?

Comment: I'm writing this driver for some embedded system and unfortunately there is no support for systemtap.

Comment: There are multiple other options to trace kernel: kprobes, ftrace, `pr_debug()`. But are you sure that you need to trace all path? Haven't you tried to add debug print into your own driver?

Comment: Yes, I've got debug printk's in my driver and they print info about received packets, and those packets are succesfully passed to the kernel. Kernel also reports receiving data (it also contains my printk's). The problem seems to be between kernel and user-space.

Answer (score 0):

`udp_rcv()` is a callback that is passed to `struct net_protocol` as a `.handler`.
You may either look at usage of this handler field in the structure, or you can also see if some error occurs. There is a callback `err_handler`. Maybe packet loss happens here and error handler will be called.

P. S. Remember that UDP does not guarantee 100% transmit success, and one lost packet out of 100 might be expected behavior. (:

Comment: Unfortunately err_handler is not called in my case